# Simple Java Mail API: Mail queue for send but did not receive any email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I writing a email client using simple java mail API and it queue for sending but I did not receive any email.

Execution Info:

> INFO: SESSION[1] bridging to remote proxy http://10.64.150.9:8080,
>   username: kwong@who.int, proxy bridge @ localhost:1081

My Code:

```
public void sendEmail() {
        try {
            init();
            DataSource fileData = new FileDataSource(new File(".\\report\\Test-Report.html"));

            Email aEmail = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                    .from("Peter Wong", "peterapiit@gmail.com")
                    .to(recipientList)
                    .withSubject("ePQS Automation Testing Report")
                    .withPlainText("Please find the ePQS Automation Testing Report from attachment")
                    .withAttachment("ePQS Automation Test Report", fileData)
                    .withBounceTo("kwong@who.int")
                    .buildEmail();

            Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
                    .withSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "peterapiit@gmail.com", "1234")
                    .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
                    .withProxy("http://10.64.150.9", 8080, "kwong@who.int", crypt.decryptPwd(".\\password\\peter_wong_wims.txt"))
                    .withSessionTimeout(10 * 1000)
                    .clearEmailAddressCriteria() // turns off email validation
                    .withDebugLogging(true)
                    .buildMailer();

            mailer.sendMail(aEmail, true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogManager.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I"m behind corporate proxy and connect to internet require this corporate proxy. 
What is the problem? Please help. A billion thanks in advance.

PS: Occasionally i encounter this error

> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout 10000; Using SOCKS host, port:
>   localhost, 1081;

Latest:

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0 Dec 31, 2018 3:40:03 PM
>   org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.socks.socks5server.AnonymousSocks5Server
>   run INFO: Starting proxy server at port 1081 Dec 31, 2018 3:40:03 PM
>   org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.socks.socks5server.AnonymousSocks5Server
>   run INFO: waiting for new connection... DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>   DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication DEBUG SMTP:
>   protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=kwong,
>   password= DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP:
>   trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false Dec
>   31, 2018 3:40:03 PM
>   org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.socks.socks5server.SocksSession
>    INFO: SESSION[1] opened from /127.0.0.1:36846 Dec 31, 2018
>   3:40:03 PM
>   org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.socks.socks5server.AnonymousSocks5Server
>   run INFO: waiting for new connection... Dec 31, 2018 3:40:03 PM
>   org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.socks.AuthenticatingSocks5Bridge
>   createSocketAuthenticated INFO: SESSION[1] bridging to remote proxy
>   https://10.64.150.9:8080, username: kwong@who.int, proxy bridge @
>   localhost:1081

Comment: Looks like you have firewall on some ports or domain of Gmail... Need to ask permission for it

Comment: You can test it this code on outside of your company and you shouldn't have issues... JIC you need to active to send messages through API of Gmail..  You can test it doing a ping to "smtp.gmail.com" and test the port 587

Comment: I can ping smtp.gmail.com without any problems.

Comment: With that port?

Comment: As I mentioned you this can be caused by firewall or something related on it,  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511080/mailconnectexception-couldnt-connect-to-host-port-smtp-gmail-com-465-timeo can help you, if that is helpful you can upvote my comments

Comment: I just type ping smtp.gmail.com without the port number. How to ping with port number?

Comment: You can use some website tester perhaps this http://portquiz.net helps you

Comment: Please see my latest edit at original post which show the error.

Comment: Yes, I did. I saw the error message, the error message is displayed after 10 seconds by timeout because you don't have outgoing/incoming 587 port and incoming mail server...

Comment: What is the meaning? I don' understand your explanation.

Comment: Please see my latest edited post at original thread.

Comment: As I mentioned you before this answer  below will help you, it's the same that I told you about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511080/mailconnectexception-couldnt-connect-to-host-port-smtp-gmail-com-465-timeo

Answer (score 0):

Check with your proxy, I think it is expecting HTTPS rather than HTTP so it is making delay.

Comment: Please see my latest edit at original post which show the error.

Comment: Try with port 465 once.

Comment: I try with 465 but error appear like following: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout 10000; Using SOCKS host, port: localhost, 1081;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: SOCKS server general failure
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnectSMTPTransport.java:740
org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.mailsender.MailSender.sendMailClosure(MailSender.java:265)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SOCKS server general failure

Comment: Did you allow to send mail from source mail to other mail through Java., if not go to your source mail and allow it (It may appear as small toolbar/pop in the access screen).